# How to handle WebSocket client events

Tags: c#, event-handling, websocket

I need to handle the State events from this WebSocket client (`ReadyState`), but I get an error when implementing the `EventHandler`, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The error I get is:

> Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'WebSocketSharp.WebSocketState' and 'System.EventHandler'

Here is how I'm trying to implement the eventhandler:

```cs
this.ws.ReadyState += new EventHandler(webSocketClient_StatusChange);
```

Here is the code:

```cs
WebSocket ws;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ws.ReadyState += new EventHandler(webSocketClient_StatusChange);
}

private void webSocketClient_StatusChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("WebSocket Status Changed...");
}

public void webSocketClientConnection()
{
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://"192.168.1.165":1258");

    {
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                string value = (e.Data);
             // More code goes here
            };

        ws.Connect();
        ws.Send("Welcome message");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReadyState is a property which will hold a value indicating:

- CONNECTING (0)
- OPEN (1)
- CLOSING (2)
- CLOSED (3)

You can use this events:

- OnClose
- OnError
- OnMessage
- OnOpen

**EDIT:**

Declare the event like this:

```
this.ws.OnClose += System.EventHandler<WebSocketSharp.CloseEventArgs>(webSocketClient_OnClose);
```

And the method `webSocketClient_OnClose` must have the correct arguments, something like this:

```
void webSocketClient_OnClose(object sender, WebSocketSharp.CloseEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: I tried this: this.ws.OnClose += new EventHandler(webSocketClient_StatusChange); but now I get this error: Cannot implicity convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler<WebSocketSharp.CloseEventArgs>' @tweellt

Comment: What websocket are you using?

Comment: Currently using WebSocketSharp; WebSocketSharp.Net; and WebSocketSharp.Net.WebSockets;

Comment: @AJ152, As a future note, always tag all involved technologies you're  working with, in this case WebSocketSharp